# Visualforce PDF and CSS overflow: hidden

Tags: visualforce, css

I am trying to create a Visualforce page that renders as PDF. My problem is that I want to display as much of a rich text field as can fit. If I use overflow: hidden in my CSS, the text is displayed, but I get blank pages that would be where the additional content would go if it weren't hidden. I can even drag and select the hidden text on the PDF.

Is there a way to use CSS in a VF page rendered as PDF to actually cut the text off?

```
<apex:page renderas="pdf" standardController="Account" showHeader="false" applyhtmltag="false">
    <head>
    <style>
    @page { 
        size: 8.5in 11in;
        @top-right {
            content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
            font-style: bold;
        }
    }
    h1 {
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <h1>{!Account.Description}</h1>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a table?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you don't have a well enough defined "container" for the postscript engine to know to only reserve the equivalent of 200px. So instead, it's allocating space for the entire content, then not printing the content that exceeds the 200px because it sees the content first instead of the container. If not a table, you probably at least need to have a Div or Span to define the container.

Comment: My actual page is a lot more complicated of course. This was a simplified version that demonstrates the same thing. It doesn't seem to matter what container I put the text in. It always gives me blank pages if the text overflows.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working) it seems like you need to explicitly specify the width of the container.

[image]

```
<apex:page renderas="{!BLANKVALUE($CurrentPage.parameters.r, 'html')}" standardController="Account" showHeader="false" applyhtmltag="false">
    <head>
    <style>
    @page { 
        size: 8.5in 11in;
        @top-right {
            content: 'Page ' counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
            font-style: bold;
        }
    }

    span {
        border: solid 2px blue;
        display: block;
        max-height:200px;

        overflow: hidden;
        width: 7in;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>{!Account.Description}</span>
        <p>{!Account.Name}</p>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't think your text is large enough to cause a page overflow. When I copy and paste your code, I get 5 pages, 4 of which are blank.

Comment: Although I did learn something. I love the way you handle the renderas.

Comment: I have 7x lorem ipsum in that acc's description :/

Comment: So, if you take off the css, does it print more than one page?

Comment: The pdf ceased to render for me now, even your vanilla version or a really simple page... Maybe I've broken something in my dev org.

Comment: Uh oh. Thanks for the time you've spent working on this.

Answer (score 1):

I still believe per my comments above that your issues are related to "containers". I'm trying to set aside a bit of time to test some variations of what I'm going to share with you, but wanted to post it and some references in the mean time since I know you're also working on this.

Background: Essentially, you're "printing" a document to a PDF printer as pages. As such, containers are even more important to consider, both in terms of a *page* level and a *box* level. See W3 Org's [Introduction to Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-box) for more on this model.

The W3 specs allow you to specify different CSS for the media type you're outputting to and also for Paged Media (usually print and projection) using `@page` and for multiple output on different via [different display methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) using the `@media` method in your CSS. Below is a simple example:

```
@media print {
    body { font-size: 10pt }
  }
  @media screen {
    body { font-size: 13px }
  }
  @media screen, print {
    body { line-height: 1.2 }
  }
```

Your specific issue though is related to orphans and widows that are being created within "boxes" when your `overflow` isn't being `hidden` as your CSS has called for which then causes pagination to occur.

In your case, these are being created when hidden text at one of the following below causes an allowed page break to occur:

- Between line boxes inside a block container box.
- Between the content edge of a block container box and the outer edges
  of its child content (margin edges of block-level children or line
  box edges for inline-level children) if there is a (non-zero) gap
  between them

These are controlled by `page-break-before`, `page-break-after` and most importantly, `page-break-inside`, all of which are set to `auto` by default. I think you want to use `page-break-inside:avoid`. These settings are also impacted to some extent by the `orphans` and `widows` setting (min no lines at start of a page and max no lines remaining at end of a page) for your smallest inner "container" or "block" that you're using.

You may also want to note the following per this reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning and see if it can be of any use to you.

> For paged media, boxes with fixed positions are repeated on every
>   page. This is useful for placing, for instance, a signature at the
>   bottom of each page. Boxes with fixed position that are larger than
>   the page area are clipped. Parts of the fixed position box that are
>   not visible in the initial containing block will not print.

In summary, I think creating your page based on a page container block model *may* be the way to solve your issue. I've never been in the situation where I needed to hide overflow text like you're in, so have never encountered this issue. Instead, I've always had the opposite one to deal with; making certain it was all visible.

When I find time to test this further, I'll report back with my findings.

Comment: Thanks for all the time and thought you've taken with this answer. I've tried putting the text in tables, divs and several other containers and I continue to get the text hidden on the page. (I can drag to highlight and select the text)

Comment: That's useful information to have. It indicates that the text was printed as "invisible" or as the same color as the background!